# Return False with a class in some defined cases

Tags: python

I would like to know if there is a way to configure a class that return False in some specific cases. What makes empty strings and empty lists return False ? How to reproduce that pattern with my own conditions (for example, return False when an attribute of that class equal a defined value) ?

An example to illustrate what I'm looking for :

```
class Foo():
  def__init__(self, value):
    self.value=value

# I would like that the class Foo return False if his value equal 0.

a = Foo(1)
b = Foo(0)

for each in [a,b]:
  if each : print( "The value isn't 0 :)" )
  else : print( "The value is 0..." )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Python 3, you need [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) method. For Python 2, you need [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__).

```
class Foo():
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def __bool__(self):
    return self.value != 0

a = Foo(1)
b = Foo(0)

for each in [a,b]:
  if each : print( "The value isn't 0 :)" )
  else : print( "The value is 0..." )
```

Answer (score 3):

Implement the `__bool__` method like this.

```
def __bool__(self):
    return flag
    # the flag is derived from the state of some attributes
    # which reflects the semantics of the object being truthy / falsy
```